# Gesture recognizer and button actions

Tags: iphone, uibutton, conflict, uigesturerecognizer, ibaction

I have a view hierarchy that looks something like this:

```
UIView (A)
UIView > UIImageView
UIView > UIView (B)
UIView > UIView (B) > Rounded Rect Button
UIView > UIView (B) > UIImageView
UIView > UIView (B) > UILabel
```

I've attached gesture recognizer(s) to my UIView (B). The problem that i'm facing is that i don't get any actions for the Rounded Rect Button which is inside the UIView (B). The singleTap gesture recognizer captures/overrides the button's Touch Up Inside event.

How can i make it work? I thought that the responder chain hierarchy will make sure that the button touch event will be given preference, and it WILL get triggered! What am i missing?

Here's some related code:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle (Gesture recognizer setup)

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // double tap gesture recognizer
    UITapGestureRecognizer *dtapGestureRecognize = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapGestureRecognizer:)];
    dtapGestureRecognize.delegate = self;
    dtapGestureRecognize.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self.viewB addGestureRecognizer:dtapGestureRecognize];

    // single tap gesture recognizer
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognize = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureRecognizer:)];
    tapGestureRecognize.delegate = self;
    tapGestureRecognize.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [tapGestureRecognize requireGestureRecognizerToFail:dtapGestureRecognize];
    [self.viewB addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognize];

    // add gesture recodgnizer to the grid view to start the edit mode
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *pahGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureRecognizerStateChanged:)];
    pahGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    pahGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
    [self.viewB addGestureRecognizer:pahGestureRecognizer];

    [dtapGestureRecognize release];
    [tapGestureRecognize release];
    [pahGestureRecognizer release];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Button actions

- (IBAction)buttonTouchUpInside:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%s, %@", __FUNCTION__, sender);
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Gesture recognizer actions


- (void)singleTapGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)doubleTapGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)longPressGestureRecognizerStateChanged:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
            NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest way is to set cancelsTouchesInView = false

Answer (score 182, accepted):

In the "shouldReceiveTouch" method you should  add a condition that will return NO if the touch is in the button.

This is from apple [SimpleGestureRecognizers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html) example.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    // Disallow recognition of tap gestures in the segmented control.
    if ((touch.view == yourButton)) {//change it to your condition
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

hope it will help

**Edit**

As Daniel noted you must conform to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` for it to work.

shani

Comment: Ah!!! Yes, i forgot about this -gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch: method. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Although this solves my problem, but i still don't know why the responder hierarchy is not working in this case. It probably should, but it's not being handled by Apple.

Comment: UIGestureRecognizer behavior is clearly described as separate from the "normal" responder chain.
This is a design decision by Apple.

Comment: Remember to conform to the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate Protocol and set the UIGestureRecognizer's delegate to that object.

Comment: For broader use, consider some variant on Ramesh's or flypig's test clauses. In my case, for example, I ended up with the line: `if ( [touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]] || [[touch.view superview] isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] ) {`... Note that tableview cells get "touched" in their contentView, which is a member of a private class, so there we check the superview's class instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In my case, I ran into the same problem but I discovered it only until I tested in the actual device. Running the app in the simulator without using UIGestureDelegate as indicated in this answer worked as expected though incorrectly.

Comment: can we detect direction within this method

Answer (score 51):

I also had the same problem , then i tried with

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {      //change it to your condition
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

It is working now perfectly.........

Comment: i only missed the `myGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;`

Answer (score 20):

Generally speaking, we use below delegate method to avoid the touch in all kinds of UIControls:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if (([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]])) {
         return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Note: DO NOT do this check (check the recognizer.view class type) the gestureRecognizerShouldBegin, it won't work.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a **Swift 3.0** version:

```
extension UIViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view is UIButton {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Don't forget to:

`Make your tapper object delegate to self (e.g: tapper.delegate = self)`

Answer (score 6):

The best solution is to my mind using code snippet below:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    return !CGRectContainsPoint(self.menuButton.frame, touchLocation);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a Swift version:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if (touch.view!.isKindOfClass(UIButton)) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Don't forget to:

1. Make you class conform to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`
2. Make your tapper object delegate to self (e.g: `tapper.delegate = self`)

Answer (score 1):

for Swift 5 inside the delegate you can just add:

```
return (touch.view is UIButton) ? false : true
```

Comment: Could be even simpler: `return !(touch.view is UIButton)`

Comment: Even without the return! (If it's a one-liner)

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of Vivienne answer:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let location = touch.location(in: view)
    return !someView.frame.contains(location)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My case was the following :

```
UIView (with tap gesture)
├-> UIView (named "textFieldView")
    ├-> UIControl
    ├-> UITextField
    ├-> UIView (over the textField, with a tap gesture)

╭──────────────────────────────╮
│ ╭──────────────────────────╮ │
│ │ ╭──╮  ┌╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶┐ │ │
│ │ ╰──╯  └╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶╴╶┘ │ │
│ ╰──────────────────────────╯ │
└──────────────────────────────┘
```

The tapGesture on the upper UIView was causing a conflict with the UIControl target. The target was called if the target was setup with `touchDown` (but not called for `touchUpInside`) or if I was changing the inheritance from `UIControl` to `UIButton` while keeping the target setup on event `touchUpInside`.

What I do to solve that is :
upper view is setup as delegate of its tap gesture.
Function `func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool` is implemented (in upper UIView) like that :

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let touchLocationRelatedToTextFieldView = touch.location(in: textFieldView)
    return textFieldView.frame.contains(touchLocationRelatedToTextFieldView) == false
}
```

With that delegate function implemented I'm now able to keep my UIControl and the target setup on `touchUpInside`! :)