# Clicking on UIButton not working when in the presence of a single Tap UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, selector, gesture-recognition, ibaction

I have a view based Window, on the view I added single tap `UIGestureRecognizer`. I then added a new popover type view, which let's name "Popover view", on this view with a `UIButton' on it.

So now when I click on `UIButton`, it calls the  single tap `UIGestureRecognizer` action, but I want it to go into `UIButton` method.

Basically, the structure is:

UIViewCintroller.view + single tap `UIGestureRecognizer` ---> on top added (A "Popover View" + `UIButton` on it).

Now I want it to do something when the `UIButton` is clicked, and the single tap `UIGestureRecognizer`.

But it is only calling the single tap `UIGestureRecognizer` method.

Thanks.

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825199/gesture-recognizer-and-button-actions