# Does Button Tap Event Get Overridden by Tap Gesture Recognizer?

Tags: cocoa-touch, events, uigesturerecognizer

I have a button that I want to make disappear if anything is tapped other than the button. So I set the target:action: for the delete button:

```
[self.deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

followed later by adding the tap gesture recognizer to the containing view:

```
[self.superview addGestureRecognizer:self.tapOutsideDelete];
```

When I do this, the action for deleteButton is not executed, as if the button tap is not recognized. The gesture recognizer does work in this case. But it also works when I tap deleteButton, which leads me to think that the tap gesture recognizer has priority over the button tap.

If I remove the gesture recognizer, deleteButton works correctly.

I clearly don't understand how to handle these two events together. What do I need to do?

(deleteButton is mimicking the delete button of a table view cell, but in this case I have it in a header view. I expect to call a method to make the delete button to disappear when I tap anywhere in the table except the button itself, the same way it works in a cell.)

Comment: You may get a bit of weirdness adding the gesture recognizer to self.superview instead of self (or self.view if it's a view controller). This would add it to the tableview which contains the header view, rather than to the header view, which may or may not be what you intend.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gesture recognizer and button actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825199/gesture-recognizer-and-button-actions)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, the tap gesture gets first crack at the tap. You need to implement the `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
            shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    if (touch.view == self.deleteButton) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly. It took a little digging to discover that this is a delegate method of the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol, so the delegate pointer must also be set.

Comment: @Jim: sorry, I was going to add that. It's frustrating how so many iOS tutorials etc. on the web don't contain *all* the information you need for a solution, and I just added to it.