# How to determine whether the user touched the toolbar item or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I had a toolbar in which i am adding 3 buttons as UItoolbaritems.Now i am also adding a gesture recogniser also to the toolbar to show and hide that toolbar.But I need to distinguish betwwen whether the touch is coming from the button or outside to carry through my functions.I tried this `

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height -12, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 44);

    self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:40/255.0 green:40/255.0 blue:40/255.0 alpha:1.0];  


    buttonGoBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonTouchUp:)];
```

buttonGoBack.tag=1;

```
    UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    fixedSpace.width = 30;


    buttonGoForward = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"forward_icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(forwardButtonTouchUp:)];
    buttonGoForward.tag=2;

    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [self.navigationController.toolbar addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];



      NSMutableArray *toolBarButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [toolBarButtons addObject:buttonGoBack];
    [toolBarButtons addObject:fixedSpace];
    [toolBarButtons addObject:buttonGoForward];
```

`

and i had done the gesture recogniser as `

```
 if(sender.view.tag==1)
           [self performSelector:@selector(backButtonTouchUp:) withObject:nil];
        else if(sender.view.tag==2)
           [self performSelector:@selector(forwardButtonTouchUp:) withObject:nil];
         else
          {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:.50 
                      animations:^{
         if(self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.y==[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height -12)
                         self.navigationController.toolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height -44, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 44);
         else
                            self.navigationController.toolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height -12, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 44);   

                      }]
}
```

`
But the buttons actions are not performing.Can anybody help me to find out where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIGesture View delegate let u ignore touch when UIBarButtonItem is clicked and clicking on UIToolBar will hide your toolbar as u have coded:-

```
 gestureRecognizer.delegate=self;

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (![touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES; // handle the touch
}
```

Answer (score 1):

might be this Solution helps you..! you can **isKindOfClass** as bellow in to your Gesture Action.

for example you can do it with bellow:-

```
 NSArray *subs = [self.yourviewcontroller.view subviews];
    for (UIToolbar *child in subs) {
        if ([child isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]]) {

            for (UIView *v in [child items])
            {
                if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]])
                {
                    UIBarButtonItem *b = (UIBarButtonItem*)v;

                    NSLog(@"found");
                    //do something with b you can also fond your clickable Barbutton Item.
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Or other solution as suggest but Herçules delegate But i need edit this like bellow

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
            shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    if (touch.view == buttonGoForward) {
        return NO;
    }
    if (touch.view == buttonGoBack) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

visit this referance:-

[Does Button Tap Event Get Overridden by Tap Gesture Recognizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164973/does-button-tap-event-get-overridden-by-tap-gesture-recognizer)

Answer (score 0):

The gesture recogniser is set on toolbar so the sender always is toolbar,
it means

```
if(sender.view.tag==1)
```

this condition will not work.
What you can do instead is to use 
`UIView` `hitTest:withEvent` method or
use one action/selector for every button, 
then you can use tags of individual button to know which bar button has called that action.

```
[buttonGoBack setAction:@selector(buttonTapped:)]
[fixedSpace setAction:@selector(buttonTapped:)];
[buttonGoForward setAction:@selector(buttonTapped:)];

- (IBAction)buttontapped:(id)sender{
if(sender.tag == 0)
{
  // perform some action
}
else if(sender.tag == 1){
  // perform some action
}
}
```

Comment: see my edits... if i understood your problem correctly than this should help you.

Comment: the problem here is how can i get the button from my recognisers actions

Comment: You need to do it via setting gesture recogniser on to the toolbar and by not setting actions on individual bar button items?