# Add Longpress gesture and Click event on UIButton

Tags: iphone, ipad, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, long-press

I am new to iPhone.

I want to add both a long press gesture and a click event to my Button, is this possible?

When I add both events to the button and then long press, my click event gets fired (on click I navigate to a new page), but my long press event never gets fired.

Here is my code snippet:

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(xpos, ypos, 120,130);
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ibook2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"32"]];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

LongPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[LongPress addTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
LongPress.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
[button addGestureRecognizer:LongPress];
[LongPress release];

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

How do I add both events?

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825199/gesture-recognizer-and-button-actions?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the line as follows,

```
     [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You click event will be fired as soon you touch the button if you use touchdown event. TouchupInside fires the action on touchup.

To get title ,

```
 - (void)longPressDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[gestureRecognizer view];
    NSLog(@"%@",[button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
}
```

Comment: Thanx this is working, How to Get Button Text of Longpressed button ?

Comment: `NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:documentsDirectory error: NULL];
    documentsDirectory=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/%@",[btn titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]];` I am getting error at last line why ? is there any syntax mistake ?

Comment: try this method instead. stringByAppendingPathComponent. you do not need to add the '/' yourself.

Comment: yes i need to append `/` by my self. i tried with `stringByAppendingPathComponent` facing same problem.