# UIButton swipe instead of click

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

While running my app the buttons are acting strange. Instead of click they react only on swipe. They do get blue on clicking, but no action occurs, and if i swipe them they act as they should. On emulator everything works as predicted by clicking. I haven't implemented any methods for swiping buttons or etc. What could be the problem ?

UPDATED :

```
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[save addTarget:self action:@selector(saveInfo)


forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
[TableControll.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];


-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [[_textFields objectAtIndex:0] resignFirstResponder];
    [[_textFields objectAtIndex:1] resignFirstResponder];
    [[_textFields objectAtIndex:2] resignFirstResponder];
    [[_textFields objectAtIndex:3] resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Without dismiss keyboard the buttons work fine, so how should i make them work together without issues ?

Comment: refer the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825199/gesture-recognizer-and-button-actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Use this method for differentiate the tap event and button Event...

Comment: In what way should i use it ?

Comment: This method is delegate method of UIGestureRecognizer (which decides whether receive gesture or not)..no need to call any where, just copy above method in class.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this was my solution:

```
tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```