# UIPanGestureRecognizer passes the event down to a button underneath

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a side panel that has a UIImageView to which I attached a UIPanGestureRecognizer so that you could push/pull the sidebar.
It works well.

Thing is that I have some buttons that happen to sometimes occur underneath that sidebar. If I pull it and a button is underneath, the button would fire simultaneously with the Pan.

I am not sure what the problem is, so I find it hard to solve. 
Why does my UIImageView pass the UIPanGestureRecognizer event on down the chain?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with this, but I think you might find your answer by looking through [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825199/gesture-recognizer-and-button-actions).

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved with delegation. 
I disable the events on toucheBegan if a BOOL called isPanning is set to YES for all buttons.
The protocol defines only one function:

```
-(void)setPanning:(BOOL)isPanning;
```

in the touchedBegan I check to see if the value is YES, if so I don't fire that event.
I wished it would be simpler.