# Stop a UIGestureRecognizer from operating on UIButtons inside a UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've attached a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to a `UIView` in my application. If the user double-taps it, the buttons inside that view get randomly re-arranged. Working fine, lovely.

However, the user can also trigger this by double-tapping one of the buttons themselves, or even by tapping two buttons on different parts of the screen.

Is there a sensible / easy way to have this double-tap only work if the two taps are within `x` number of pixels, and on the view itself, not any elements within it such as these `UIButton`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the usual way to do this is with `shouldReceiveTouch`.  Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825199/gesture-recognizer-and-button-actions) for a lengthy discussion and all the details.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to attach a single tap gesture recognizer to the buttons -- this will preempt the button's normal touch events, so you would have to put the button's action method in the gesture recognizer's action method. Then, you would add a dependency to the double tapper to have it only fire if the single tapper fails:

```
[self.doubleTapper requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.tapper];
```

Comment: I actually already have one of those on the buttons, which works fine. But double-tapping the button still triggers the view's double-tap method.

Comment: @lukech, are you sure you have your outlets connected correctly? I've tested this, and it worked for me.