# iOS overlapped views and UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view with a `UIButton` inside like this: [snapshot 01 http://imageshack.us/a/img827/7240/screenshot20130220at333.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img827/7240/screenshot20130220at333.png)

The button is bound to an `IBAction`:

```
-(IBAction)deleteButtonPressed :(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"DeleteButtonPressed");
}
```

I also have another view that shows a collection of the last view: [image: snapshot 02]

In the controller of this view, at some point I have this:

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [preview addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

And this:

```
- (void)tapAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

    EditorViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EditorViewController"];
    vc.narration = preview.narration;
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Done";
    vc.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
    vc.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Done";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

So, when I touch in the preview, I load another view. My problems come when I tap the button. In this case, the function `-(IBAction)deleteButtonPressed: (id)sender` doesn't get executed but the `tapAction` does. Also, the button change while is pressed. I tried to don't add the GestureRecognizer and then `-(IBAction)deleteButtonPressed :(id)sender` is executed.

What I am doing wrong? How can I achieve that when tap on the button, the view underneath doesn't capture the gesture?

Comment: make sure ibaction is connected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the `shouldReceiveTouch` method (which is part of the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol).

More info about your problem here:

[Gesture recognizer and button actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825199/gesture-recognizer-and-button-actions)