# Pass taps through a UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I'd like to detect swipe on the entire screen, however, the screen contains `UIButton`s, and if the user taps one of these buttons, I want the Touch Up Inside event to be triggered.
I've create a `UIView` on the top of my screen, and added a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on it to detect the swipe, but now I need to pass the gesture through that view when I detect that it's a tap rather than a swipe.

I know how to differentiate the gestures, but I've no idea on how to pass it to the view below.

Can anyone help on that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your answer. The link helped me to solve part of my problem.
I've set the buttons as subviews of my gestureRecognizer view and I can now start a swipe from one of the buttons (and continue to use the buttons as well). I managed to prevent the buttons to go to the "down" state by using the following code :

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDetected:)];
swipe.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
swipe.delaysTouchesBegan =YES;
swipe.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
[self.gestureRecognitionView addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a BOOL property of UIGestureRecognizer cancelsTouchesInView. default is yes. set it to NO , and the touches will pass thru to the UIView

also have a look at the  [solution for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825199/gesture-recognizer-and-button-actions)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent the recognizer from receiving the touch at all, `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` has a method `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` you can use:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    // don't override any other recognizers
    if (gestureRecognizer != panRecognizer) {
        return YES;
    }

    CGPoint touchedPoint = [touch locationInView:self.someButton];

    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.someButton.bounds, touchedPoint) == NO;
}
```