# UISwitch is firing UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: uiview, uiswitch, uicontrol, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm setting a gesture recognizer (swipe right) on a view like this:

```
[self.currentViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:self.swipeRecognizer];
```

However, the view has some UIControls that respond to touches. They are custom switches which allow you to turn them on and off by panning them, exactly like a UISwitch. Therefore when you pan one of the switches to the right, the swipe gesture recognizer gets invoked.

I still want to keep the swipe recognizer on the rest of the view, but how can I cancel it if you're touching one of the switches?

Answer (score 4):

Found a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825199/gesture-recognizer-and-button-actions?rq=1).

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if (([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]])) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```