# Can't touch UIButton in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I am programmatically creating buttons in a view inside `UIScrollView`. I also have programmatically created `UITextField`. I can select and enter data into the text fields all day long. But I cannot get any sign the buttons are being touched. I can add them to the main view and they work. But when added to the view inside the `UIScrollView`, they are lost in another dimension. I've read plenty of info about setting `userInteraction`, `delayContentTouches`, and intercepting via `gestureRecognizer`. The last might be related to my problem. I return `NO` via `[touch.view isDescendantOfView:self.myScrollViewName]`. I can't get it to trigger via `[touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]`. Which makes me think I have a more fundamental error I am missing?

related:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6825839/4050489

edited to add button code per request:

```
        self.myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        self.myButton.frame = myButtonFrame;
        self.myButton.enabled = interface.isActive;
        self.myButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.myButton.exclusiveTouch = YES;

        self.myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        //self.myButton. = YES;

        self.myButton.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
        self.myButton.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        self.myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

        [self.myButton setTag:interface.tag];
        [self.myButton setTitle:interface.Name forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navigatePartButtons:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.myButton setEnabled:YES];  //error check


        [self.partSetupView addSubview:self.myButton];
```

`partSetupView` is a `UIView` in the `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Please post some code samples as to how you're adding these buttons to the ScrollView

Comment: You can explicitly enable `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` to see if it's even recognizing a touch down event.

Comment: I don't think it does recognize it. You don't even get the text flicker unless added to a `UIView` outside of `UIScrollView`. Plus it doesn't cause the delegate to fire either. `UIScrollView` is interfering or not hooked up right but the solutions I've read so far do not seem to prevent that interference. Does seem to be a common issue. But the text fields worked effortlessly.

Comment: Make sure `userInteractionEnabled` is set to yes for your scroll view

Comment: Yes, already did that. Also, shouldn't a downvote at least mean that person has an easy answer?

Comment: I don't know why you got the downvote, but I have plenty of buttons inside scrollViews so I'm not sure what could be going wrong. Is your `partSetupView` actually inside the scrollView, not behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this sample Code:

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIScrollView *myScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 300)];
    myScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:myScroll];

    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [myScroll addSubview:myView];

    UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100)];
    myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [myView addSubview:myButton];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}
-(void)btnClick{
    NSLog(@"Button Click");
}
@end
```

Comment: This helped find the answer. Your button worked. Mine didn't. No real difference between them. Except location. Despite seeing the buttons and despite their scrolling, I didn't have my `UIView` frame (partSetupView frame size) set the same as my `UIScrollView`. I've seen this eluded to but didn't understand what they meant until I fought with it myself.

Comment: Gave you an uptick cause your comment put me on the right path!