# iOS - UIButton requires two taps with UIControlEventTouchUpInside

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicontrolevents

For some reason my UIButton requires two taps to trigger and I don't understand why, this is not the desired functionality and all of my other buttons work as expected

Here is the `addTarget` code:

```
[self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(publishButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

My function `publishButtonTapped` is not triggered until the second tap in quick succession.

There must be something else I am overlooking, so any insight appreciated

My button and layout is created programmatically, so there is no XIB or storyboard.

Comment: this might occur, when you have any tap gestures enabled on the view that contains the button

Comment: are you sure you dont have any other tap gestures present in the view ?

Comment: if you have any tap gestures in your view, this should solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825199/gesture-recognizer-and-button-actions

Comment: @Mr.T thanks, I ended up making the button bigger. Strange because I have smaller buttons that are more responsive. I will look at your suggestions because it sounds on track

Comment: @Mr.T I got it, there was another way to arrange all of my views, thanks for the hint about conflicting tap gestures!